# dynamically show and hide button according to computed property in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, v-model, conditional-rendering

i want to show delete button for each comment that a particular user made, but i am unable to do it, i am using v-bind to disable delete buttton for others comment, so that user cant delete others comment, but its still visible for all the comments i.e (for other users as well ). suppose i am a user i comment 3 times then delete button should show on my comments only not on others comment. can some one please help me to achieve this?

```
My code snippet is below

<div class="comment-list" v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment._id"> 
   <div class="paragraph" :class="[name, onCaretButtonClick ? 'paragraph' : 'hide']">
    <span class="names" id="comment-desc"> 
      <label class="comm-name">{{ comment.name }}</label>
      <button class="like-btn" id="like-comment"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button>
      <label> {{ comment.likes + ' likes' }} </label>
        <button v-bind:disabled="isCommentIdMatched" v-on:click="deleteComment(comment.userId)" 
         class="del-btn">delete</button>
    </span>
    <p>{{ comment.comment }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

below is deleteComment function and computed properties that i am using

```
computed: {
comments() {
  return store.state.comments 
},
getUserId() {
  return store.state.user._id
},
isCommentIdMatched() {
  let comments = store.state.comments
  let value = false
  if(comments) {
    comments.forEach((comment) => {
      if(comment.userId.match(this.getUserId)) {
        value = true
      }
    })
    return value
  }
  else {
    return value
  }
}
},

 methods: {
   deleteComment: function(commentUserId) {
   let userId = store.state.user._id
   if(commentUserId.match(userId)) {
    console.log('yes matched')
   }
 },

}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to write isCommentIdMatched property, instead you can use change some lines.

add v-bind="comments" in below line

```
<div v-bind="comments" class="comment-list" v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment._id">
```

and add v-if="comment.userId && comment.userId.match(getUserId)" in below button

```
<button v-if="comment.userId && comment.userId.match(getUserId)" v-on:click="deleteComment(comment.userId)" class="del-btn">delete</button>
```